# How would I get a Texture in the project and send it over to discord using a webhook? Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

What I am trying to do is take a texture(any texture) from unity and use a webhook from discord to send it to discord.

This is what I have so far keep in mind I started coding not long ago so I'm not very familiar with this;

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
public class SendMessage : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string Message, Subject;
    public string webhook;
    public Texture2D screenshot;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
    
    }
    IEnumerator SendWebHook(string link, string message, System.Action<bool> action)
    {
         WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
        form.AddField("content", message + screenshot.EncodeToPNG());
        using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post(link, form))
        {
            yield return www.SendWebRequest();

            if(www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
            {
                Debug.Log(www.error);
                action(false);
            }
            else
            {
                action(true);
            }
        }
    }
    public void send()
    {
        StartCoroutine(SendWebHook(webhook, Subject + Message, (success) =>
        {
            if(success)
            {
                Debug.Log("good");
            }
        }));
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use coroutines for I/O.  Either use `async/await` or a Unity Job.

Comment: @MickyD how would I do that exacty i only know how to do webhooks with Coroutines? Sorry if im asking for to much

Comment: Here you go: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/JobSystemJobSystems.html.  Remember coroutines work by multiplexing each slice across the Main Unity Thread responsible for the render loop.   Therefore the highest frame rate in the render loop is at the mercy of the slowest coroutine.

Comment: No problem good sir.  Happy Unity'ing :)